# Reading json file array Java Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String strJson=null;
        String data = "";
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("urls.json");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte [] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            strJson = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
            // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
            JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);

            //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("urls");

            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                data +=jsonObject;
            }
            output.setText(data);
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

I got 0 errors. But nothing displays on textview.
my json file looks like

```
{
  "urls": 
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of key "urls" is not JSONObject, it's just array of String. You can simply do like this

```
    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
       data += jsonArray.getString(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change `data +=jsonObject;` to `data +=String.valueOf(jsonObject)` . you need to convert your `JSONObject` first to `String`.